# Is there a good tool to design JQuery Mobile Interfaces in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, typescript

I am looking for a good tool to speed up my gui design tasks in Visual Studio. I develop Mobile Apps with TypeScript, Backbone JS and JQM.

Is there a good tool to design JQM GUIs in a visual editor? The best match I found was codiqa.com but it's web based and very expensive (for gui only). Any ideas?

AND if you don't have a tip: Is there any requirement for this or am I an exotic? I am thinking about starting my own project.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a requirement for this. The same logic why Visual Studio no longer has an HTML "designer", only an editor, for MVC applications.

The main reason is interoperability (browser compat) and live editing (Code midway between starting and the user having carried out a number of actions). When you have a JS heavy site the non executed html is not very useful to look at.

For live editing Tools like Expression blend are potentially useful but I don't know of anyone who uses it for production.

"codiqa.com" is more a platform / prototype tool than a jquery ui design tool. And once you need super custom behaviours you would export their code into your good old editor and start cracking code like you used to. Not saying it isn't useful to get an easy start, but saying that it isn't the end all.